# toUppercase the first letter of an input text while tapping

Tags: jquery, input

I found this code and helped me a little bit to what I want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('keyup', function(event) {
        $(this).val(function(i, v){
            return v.replace(/[a-zA-z]/, function(c){
               return c.toUpperCase();
            })
        })
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbxVx/1/)

The problem is when I change `.toUppercase()` with something like : `.bold()`
it adds tags inside the input element `<b>`.

So basically it doesn't work.

What I want to do is a simple input element where the first letter (anumber actually) is going to be bold and the next 2 letters are going to be positioned vertically on top (it's a date input)
as in: 1st 2sn 3rd 4th 5th (of a month).

I hope I explained good.

Comment: You should consider using a hacky solution for this, this is not possible by using a normal `input` element.

Comment: lol isn't this obvious ? d you have any real suggestion or a code !

Comment: Yes, this is, of course, as you knew this was obvious what  had you tried for doing it? This is not a _give me the code_ website.

Comment: 1- i didn't ask for the entire code but just a small part of it just to give me a push to start because am running out of ideas and i did my home work and tried so many codes
2-you just suggested that i find a solution ! lol isn't that what am here for ? suggest to others to find a solution is not a solution .. that just obvious